# Gradle task runs even if upToDateWhen returns true

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am learning Gradle. I have a task where I have used upToDateWhen method . It is hardcoded to always return true. I heard that if it is true the method is considered up to date and it wont run.
But when I execute the task it runs for the first time and then it stops running from the second time saying its upto date. I thought it wont run even for the first time. Am i missing something. Please shed some light .

```
task inputOutputCheckWithMethodCall(group:'Learn-Task-Execution',description:'This task is used to learn how gradle executes tasks by evaluating input and output through method call during execution time'){
    outputs.upToDateWhen {true}

       doFirst{

        println 'Executing task inputOutputCheckWithMethodCall'  

    }
       }
```

Comment: The outputs being up to date is only part of the calculation as to whether a task is up to date. See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2467#issuecomment-315184626

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks for the link and explanation ....  Please make it as an answer so that I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputs being up to date is only part of the calculation as to whether a task is up to date. See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2467#issuecomment-315184626

> `outputs.upToDateWhen { true }` doesn't mean "the task is up-to-date."
> It just means that the outputs are up-to-date for that particular
> spec. Gradle will still do its own up-to-date checks.
>
> The other thing that may be confusing is where the task's actions are
> defined. If the actions are defined in the build script, the build
> script itself is an input to the task. So changes to the build script
> will make the task out-of-date.
>
> So if I had a task like:
>
> ```
> task myTask {
>     def outputFile = file("output.txt")
>     outputs.file outputFile
>     doLast {
>         outputFile.text = "Done"
>     }
>
>     outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
> }
> ```
>
> Whenever I run this, myTask is out-of-date. If I switch the false to
> true, the first time I run it, the task is out-of-date still (because
> the buildscript changed). When I run it again, it would be up-to-date
> (all inputs are the same). You'll see this at --info level logging.
>
> ```
> Task ':myTask' has additional actions that have changed
> ```